# Test for differences in frequencies of categorical variable with multiple responses

Tags: categorical-data, independence, contingency-tables

**Background**

Interviews with two groups of therapists were conducted: experienced therapists and inexperienced therapists.

Each statement of the interview was classified into 9 different categories. It is possible that a statment is categorized into multiple categories at once.

**Question**

How could one test whether the frequencies of the 9 categories differ between the two groups of therapists or not?

I assume that a simple chi-squared test or Fisher test would be inappropriate here because of the possibility of multiple responses?

Comment: A better option here seems to create a dummy variable for each possible response category (`yes` when the response category is chosen and `no` otherwise) and then do a separate chi-squared or Fisher's Exact test for each dummy variable.